# How to get all of the supported file formats from Graphics unit?

Tags: delphi, file, graphics, delphi-2010, formats

When any TGraphic descendant registering its own graphic file format with a class procedure TPicture.RegisterFileFormat(), they're all stored in Graphics.FileFormats global variable.

Too bad that FileFormats variable is not in the "interface" section of "Graphics.pas", so I can't access it. I need to read this variable to implement a special filter for my file-list control.

Can I get that list without manual fixing the Graphics.pas's source code?

Comment: There is also related [QC report #11837](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=11837) worth to vote

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are working with a file-list control, and presumably thus a list of filenames.  If you don't need to know the actual `TGraphic` class types that are registered, only whether a given file extension is registered or not (such as to check if a later call to `TPicture.LoadFromFile()` is likely to succeed), you can use the public `GraphicFileMask()` function to get a list of registered file extensions and then compare your filenames to that list.  For example:

```
uses
  SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Masks;

function IsGraphicClassRegistered(const FileName: String): Boolean;
var
  Ext: String;
  List: TStringList;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  Ext := ExtractFileExt(FileName);
  List := TStringList.Create;
  try
    List.Delimiter := ';';
    List.StrictDelimiter := True;
    List.DelimitedText := GraphicFileMask(TGraphic);
    for I := 0 to List.Count-1 do
    begin
      if MatchesMask(FileName, List[I]) then
      begin
        Result := True;
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or, you could simply load the file and see what happens:

```
uses
  Graphics;

function GetRegisteredGraphicClass(const FileName: String): TGraphicClass;
var
  Picture: TPicture;
begin
  Result := nil;
  try
    Picture := TPicture.Create;
    try
      Picture.LoadFromFile(FileName);
      Result := TGraphicClass(Picture.Graphic.ClassType);
    finally
      Picture.Free;
    end;
  except
  end;
end;
```

**Update:** if you want to extract the extensions and descriptions, you can use `TStringList.DelimitedText` to parse the result of the `GraphicFilter()` function:

```
uses
  SysUtils, Classes, Graphics;

function RPos(const ASub, AIn: String; AStart: Integer = -1): Integer;
var
  i: Integer;
  LStartPos: Integer;
  LTokenLen: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  LTokenLen := Length(ASub);
  // Get starting position
  if AStart < 0 then begin
    AStart := Length(AIn);
  end;
  if AStart < (Length(AIn) - LTokenLen + 1) then begin
    LStartPos := AStart;
  end else begin
    LStartPos := (Length(AIn) - LTokenLen + 1);
  end;
  // Search for the string
  for i := LStartPos downto 1 do begin
    if Copy(AIn, i, LTokenLen) = ASub then begin
      Result := i;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure GetRegisteredGraphicFormats(AFormats: TStrings);
var
  List: TStringList;
  i, j: Integer;
  desc, ext: string;
begin
  List := TStringList.Create;
  try
    List.Delimiter := '|';
    List.StrictDelimiter := True;
    List.DelimitedText := GraphicFilter(TGraphic);
    i := 0;
    if List.Count > 2 then
      Inc(i, 2); // skip the "All" filter ...
    while i <= List.Count-1 do
    begin
      desc := List[i];
      ext := List[i+1];
      j := RPos('(', desc);
      if j > 0 then
        desc := TrimRight(Copy(desc, 1, j-1)); // remove extension mask from description
      AFormats.Add(ext + '=' + desc);
      Inc(i, 2);
    end;
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
end;
```

**Update 2:** if you are just interested in a list of registered graphic file extensions, then, assuming `List` is an already created `TStrings` descendant, use this:

```
ExtractStrings([';'], ['*', '.'], PChar(GraphicFileMask(TGraphic)), List);
```

Comment: You should probably say here, as well as your comment to @Cosmin, that `GraphicFilter` can be parsed to get descriptions as well as masks.

Comment: +1 Wow! Thanks very much for pointing us at these two véry usefull `Graphics.pas` routines.

Comment: Does OP really work with file list control? I don't see anything about that in remaining comments.

Answer (score 11):

The [GlScene](http://glscene.org) project has a unit *PictureRegisteredFormats.pas* that implements a hack for that.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much, Uwe. How do you think, will it be correct if I'll publish the solution of GIScene here for community? It's open source anyway

Comment: The reason I didn't post it here by myself was that I didn't want to think about exactly that question...

Comment: @Andrew, Uwe: Googling for the filename yields http://koders.com/delphi/fid739624F9723111BEB467AA346A9D169807AA42B7.aspx?s=hook. This should be enough.

Answer (score 10):

Here's an alternative hack that might be **safer** then the `GLScene` solution. **It's still a hack**, because the desired structure is global but in the implementation section of the `Graphics.pas` unit, but my method uses a lot less "maigc constants" (hard-coded offsets into the code) and uses two distinct methods to detect the `GetFileFormats` function in `Graphics.pas`.

My code exploits the fact that both `TPicture.RegisterFileFormat` and `TPicture.RegisterFileFormatRes` need to call the `Graphics.GetFileFormats` function immediately. The code detects the relative-offset `CALL` opcode and registers the destination address for *both*. Only moves forward if both results are the same, and this adds a safety-factor. The other safety-factor is the detection method itself: even if the prologue generated by the compiler would change, as long as the first function called is `GetFileFormats`, this code finds it.

I'm not going to put the `"Warning: This will crash when Graphics.pas is compiled with the 'Use Debug DCUs' option."` at the top of the unit (as found in the `GLScene` code), because I've tested with both debug dcu's and no debug dcu's and it worked. Also tested with packages and it still worked.

This code *only works* for 32bit targets, hence the extensive use of `Integer` for pointer operations. I will attempt making this work for 64bit targets as soon as I'll get my Delphi XE2 compiler installed.

**Update:** A version supporting 64 bit can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35817804/505088

```
unit FindReigsteredPictureFileFormats;

interface

uses Classes, Contnrs;

// Extracts the file extension + the description; Returns True if the hack was successful,
// False if unsuccesful.
function GetListOfRegisteredPictureFileFormats(const List: TStrings): Boolean;

// This returns the list of TGraphicClass registered; True for successful hack, false
// for unsuccesful hach
function GetListOfRegisteredPictureTypes(const List:TClassList): Boolean;

implementation

uses Graphics;

type
  TRelativeCallOpcode = packed record
    OpCode: Byte;
    Offset: Integer;
  end;
  PRelativeCallOpcode = ^TRelativeCallOpcode;

  TLongAbsoluteJumpOpcode = packed record
    OpCode: array[0..1] of Byte;
    Destination: PInteger;
  end;
  PLongAbsoluteJumpOpcode = ^TLongAbsoluteJumpOpcode;

  TMaxByteArray = array[0..System.MaxInt-1] of Byte;
  PMaxByteArray = ^TMaxByteArray;

  TReturnTList = function: TList;

  // Structure copied from Graphics unit.
  PFileFormat = ^TFileFormat;
  TFileFormat = record
    GraphicClass: TGraphicClass;
    Extension: string;
    Description: string;
    DescResID: Integer;
  end;

function FindFirstRelativeCallOpcode(const StartOffset:Integer): Integer;
var Ram: PMaxByteArray;
    i: Integer;
    PLongJump: PLongAbsoluteJumpOpcode;
begin
  Ram := nil;

  PLongJump := PLongAbsoluteJumpOpcode(@Ram[StartOffset]);
  if (PLongJump^.OpCode[0] = $FF) and (PLongJump^.OpCode[1] = $25) then
    Result := FindFirstRelativeCallOpcode(PLongJump^.Destination^)
  else
    begin
      for i:=0 to 64 do
        if PRelativeCallOpcode(@Ram[StartOffset+i])^.OpCode = $E8 then
          Exit(StartOffset + i + PRelativeCallOpcode(@Ram[StartOffset+i])^.Offset + 5);
      Result := 0;
    end;
end;

procedure FindGetFileFormatsFunc(out ProcAddr: TReturnTList);
var Offset_from_RegisterFileFormat: Integer;
    Offset_from_RegisterFileFormatRes: Integer;
begin
  Offset_from_RegisterFileFormat := FindFirstRelativeCallOpcode(Integer(@TPicture.RegisterFileFormat));
  Offset_from_RegisterFileFormatRes := FindFirstRelativeCallOpcode(Integer(@TPicture.RegisterFileFormatRes));

  if (Offset_from_RegisterFileFormat = Offset_from_RegisterFileFormatRes) then
    ProcAddr := TReturnTList(Pointer(Offset_from_RegisterFileFormat))
  else
    ProcAddr := nil;
end;

function GetListOfRegisteredPictureFileFormats(const List: TStrings): Boolean;
var GetListProc:TReturnTList;
    L: TList;
    i: Integer;
begin
  FindGetFileFormatsFunc(GetListProc);
  if Assigned(GetListProc) then
    begin
      Result := True;
      L := GetListProc;
      for i:=0 to L.Count-1 do
        List.Add(PFileFormat(L[i])^.Extension + '=' + PFileFormat(L[i])^.Description);
    end
  else
    Result := False;
end;

function GetListOfRegisteredPictureTypes(const List:TClassList): Boolean;
var GetListProc:TReturnTList;
    L: TList;
    i: Integer;
begin
  FindGetFileFormatsFunc(GetListProc);
  if Assigned(GetListProc) then
    begin
      Result := True;
      L := GetListProc;
      for i:=0 to L.Count-1 do
        List.Add(PFileFormat(L[i])^.GraphicClass);
    end
  else
    Result := False;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I have a version that works for 64 bit. Would you like me to pastebin it for you?

Comment: The `GetListOfRegisteredPictureFileFormats()` function can be implemented differently by using `TStringList.DelimitedText` to parse the result of the public [`Graphics.GraphicFilter()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Graphics.GraphicFilter) function. This is the same function that `TOpenPictureDialog` uses to create its `Filter`. No low-level hack needed. A low-level hack would only be needed when accessing the `TFileFormat.GraphicClass` field, the registered descriptions and extensions are publically accessible, just not stright-forward.

Comment: Well, both new solutions are acceptable. I voted for both ) I unchecked the Uwe's answer until the bounty timeout will end.

Comment: @Andrew, Remy's solution is very good if one only needs the registered file extensions and descriptions. My solution is only interesting if one needs the `TGraphicClass` list - but I don't think that's very valuable. At least I can't imagine a scenario where I'd need the `TGraphicClass`.

Comment: You would need the `TGraphicClass` when you want to load from a stream, see: [QC6669](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=6669) and [QC57402](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=57402).